# распарсить с помощью регулярок qt определенное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения, qt

здравствуйте, нужно выдрать с помощью регулярок из запроса scgi выражение content_length и 27, только их, и все(если это вообще возможно)... естественно content_length может быть не 27 :

```
 auto f = QString("\"CONTENT_LENGTH\"<00>\"27\"<00>"
                  "\"SCGI\"<00>\"1\"<00>"
                  "\"REQUEST_METHOD\"<00>\"POST\"<00>"
                  "\"REQUEST_URI\"<00>\"/deepthought\"<00>\",\""
                  "\"What is the answer to life?\"");
 QRegExp rx("(\"+[a-zA-Z_/0-9]+\")");
 QStringList list1;
 int pos1 = 0;
 while ((pos1 = rx.indexIn(f, pos1)) != -1) {
    list1 << rx.cap(1);
    pos1 += rx.matchedLength();
 }
```

выводит это: "CONTENT_LENGTH" "27" "SCGI" "1" "REQUEST_METHOD" "POST" "REQUEST_URI" "/deepthought"...
хотел как-нибудь через

```
QRegExp rx("(\"+[a-zA-Z_/0-9]+\")(\\d+)");
```

и далее использовать rx.cap(2), то в итоге не удается...

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно получить значение только `CONTENT_LENGTH`, тогда именно его и вытаскивайте:

```
QRegExp rx("\"(CONTENT_LENGTH)\"<00>\"(\\d+)\"<00>");
```

Для получения всех пар ключ-значение используйте это выражение:

```
QRegExp rx("\"([\\w]+)\"<00>\"([\\w|/]+)\"<00>");
```

Соответственно имя ключа получите через `rx.cap(1)`, а значение через `rx.cap(2)`.

Comment: если не сложно, помогите с этим: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/694254/regex-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c