# regex и терминальный ноль

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, qt5

здравствуйте, необходимо выдрать из запроса scgi все заголовки и их значения через регулярки...
запрос:

```
CONTENT_LENGTH\027\0SCGI\01\0REQUEST_METHOD\0POST\0REQUEST_URI\0/deepthought\0,What is the answer to life?
```

вся проблема в терминальном нуле... уж что только не пробовал: "(\0[a-zA-Z_/]+\0)", вообще даже просто числа не находит "(\\d+)"

сам код:

```
auto f = QString("CONTENT_LENGTH\027\0SCGI\01\0REQUEST_METHOD\0POST\0REQUEST_URI\0/deepthought\0,What is the answer to life?");
QRegExp rx("(/\x00/\\d+)");    // сюда много чего перепробовал
int pos1{0}; QStringList list1;
while ((pos1 = rx.indexIn(f, pos1)) != -1) {
    list1 << rx.cap(1);
    pos1 += rx.matchedLength();
}
std::cout << list1.join(",").toStdString() << std::endl;
```

товарищ Abyx, натолкнул на мысль, однако так и не знаю как вытащить значения заголовков(например 27), после этого:

```
f = QString::fromLocal8Bit("CONTENT_LENGTH\027\0SCGI\01\0REQUEST_METHOD\0POST\0REQUEST_URI\0/deepthought\0,What is the answer to life?"
          , 96);
QRegExp rx("(\\x00*[a-zA-Z_/]+)");
```

выводится следующее:

```
  CONTENT_LENGTH,SCGI,REQUEST_METHOD,POST,REQUEST_URI,/deepthought,What,is,the,answer,to,life
```

Comment: Пробуйте `\x00`

Comment: @Visman, не помогает

Comment: Язык программирования в тегах укажите. Вероятно двойное экранирование нужно вам - `\\0`, `\\x00` и т.п.

Comment: @Visman, не прокатывает, что уж я только ни делал

Comment: @Abyx, обновил...

Comment: @Abyx, а как быть то?

Comment: @Abyx, хотите сказать что строка оканчивается на первом \0?

Comment: @Abyx, а не подскажете как так сделать? чет не могу найти подходящего конструктора

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С Вашим примером есть несколько проблем, а метод, которым Вы решили задачу решать, ей совершенно не подходит — регулярные выражения здесь вообще ни к чему (как и в большинстве случаев).

Итак, первое, Вам нужно знать длину строки `"CONTENT_LENGTH\027\0SCGI..."`, которую вычислить не получится из-за наличия нуль символов в оной. Я предполагаю, что строка эта откуда-то берётся и оттуда можно получить её длину.

Дальше, в примере, который Вами представлен, Вы пытаетесь сконструировать строку из нуль-символов и чисел, а в результате получается ерунда. Если Вы думаете, что `"\027"`, это строка состоящая из нуль-символа и числа 27, то Вы заблуждаетесь,— это число `027` в восьмеричной системе счисления.  Честно говоря, я не знаю, как это записать одной строкой, но обходной путь покажу в примере ниже.

Мой пример составлен на основе Вашего, но сокращён, чтобы упростить вычисление длины строки и прочее.

```
auto request = QByteArray("CONTENT_LENGTH\0""27\0""SCGI\0""1", 25);
auto list = request.split('\0');
// Удалим пустой элемент, появившийся из-за закрывающего нуль-символа в C-строке
list.removeLast();
for(size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); i += 2)
    qDebug() << list[i] << " = " << list[i + 1];
```

И всё, никаких регулярных выражений. Вам остаётся только адаптировать Ваш реальный код, под идею, что я привёл выше.